# How can i change header for child pages in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

[image: Parent Page Header]
First image is from parent Page, wenn i click on an item from navigation then child Page opens but i do not need same header as Parent's header, i need header with back arrow like in second image for child but without parent's header.

I have also added Sandbox link, please check App.vue, Help.vue, Help-info.vue , main.js, registerServiceWorker.js, index.js, vue.config.js ...
Others files are auto generated by this Sandbox editor.

[image: Child Page Header]
[Link For live Testing](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-framework-wjf46?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: can you show us some code and what you've tried so far?

Comment: Link added...please check..